# Apex class to test data access for each role

Tags: apex, role-hierarchy

We are redesigning our role hierarchy and add new roles. We are thinking of testing this automatically. We are thinking of building an apex class which can login as a user in all roles and do a soql query on leads, accounts and contacts and other objects. We want to populate this data in a custom object. This way we can make sure once we complete the role hierarchy we can ensure everything is good.

Is there a way in an apex class i can query role hierarchy from top and get an user and do a soql count for each object? We are trying to simulate one user per role and check data access.

Comment: The only way would be using `runAs` during a test method.

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed that this can only be done using test class with run as method. We have to use seealldata=true attribute to enable the test class to access all data in the org. From a best practice standpoint, you should not use seealldata parameter but in this situation as this is one utility class, it is fine.